# Need to calculate No of time customer visit the shop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct, window-functions

I need to calculate the number of visit of a customer to a store. Along with the item purchased. In that case , customer visit store 3 times and purchased 5 item. Now when i count the number of visit, my output is 5.

Below is the query I was trying:

```
select 
    Receipt_no,
    Customer,sales_item,
    Amount,
    sum(Amount) over (partition by customer) as total_sales,
    count(Receipt_No) over (partition by customer) as No_of_Visit 
from sales
left join customer where sales.Customer = customer.Customer
```

And my output is

```
Receipt_No  Customer  sales_item  Amount  total_sales  No_of_Visit
5           C1        Item1       100     1200         5
5           C1        Item3       200     1200         5
5           C1        item4       200     1200         5
34          C1        item1       300     1200         5
35          C1        item2       400     1200         5
```

but i want the No_of_Visit as "3"

Comment: Why in the world would you need to left join TO customer? How can a sale exist without an associated customer?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a distinct count of receipts. That could have been:

```
count(distinct receipt_no) over (partition by customer) as No_of_Visit
```

But unfortunately SQL Server does not support `distinct` in window functions. You can, however, emulate it with `dense_rank()`:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by customer order by receipt_no) 
    + dense_rank() over (partition by customer order by receipt_no desc) 
    - 1 as No_of_Visit
```